# Los state en VUEJS regresan a su valor inicial al refrescar navegador

Tags: vue.js, login, vuex, component

muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Tengo un inconveniente, estoy empezando en vuejs y estoy terminando un login; ya logré conectarme através de axios y autenticar o no al usuario. Mi problema es cuando pinto los datos del usuario en el header (Nombre, perfil, etc), en el componente header llamo al estado que guarda estos datos; los muestra normal, a continuación pego el extracto de código del header.vue

```
created() {          
          this.user = this.$store.getters.getUser;
        }
```

Como les decía, en un primer momento lo nuestra bien, pero si refresco el navegador me muestra el valor inicial de state. Los extractos de código en el store.js son los siguientes:

```
state: {
    token:localStorage.getItem('user-token') || '',
    status:'',
    user: {}
},
getters: {
    isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
    authStatus: state => state.status,
    getUser: state => state.user
}
```

Cabe recalcar que sólo estoy guardando en el localStorage el token y status; alguien me puede explicar que está pasando y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Necesitamos más información, ¿Cuando refrescas, hace la autenticación correctamente? ¿Te sale algún error en la consola? ¿Tienes Vue developer tools para comprobar como cambian el state?

Comment: Al refrescar el navegador no me sale ningún error, he puesto un console.log y me devuelve el valor inicial del state, mas no el valor que obtuvo en la mutation:
  auth_success(state, {token, user}) {
      state.status = 'success'
      state.token = token
      state.user = user
    }